# tflite_runtime : "op builtin_code out of range: 131. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model ?" with YAMNET model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am trying to use the [YAMNET model made for the Coral Board](https://tfhub.dev/google/coral-model/yamnet/classification/coral/1) on my Coral Dev Board Mini, but I can't make it work, because I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mendel/classifier_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 207, in __init__
    custom_op_registerers_by_func))
ValueError: Op builtin_code out of range: 131. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model?Registration failed.
```

The snippet of code I am using is :

```py
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
delegate = tflite.load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1')
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path='coral_yamnet.tflite', experimental_delegates=[delegate])
```

I get the same error if I don't use the delegate.

My version of `tflite_runtime` is :

```
>>> pip show tflite_runtime
Name: tflite-runtime
Version: 2.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow Lite is for mobile and embedded devices.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/
Author: Google, LLC
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/mendel/classifier_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy
Required-by:
```

And I am using Python 3.7.3.

I also tried to use it on my computer with `tensorflow.lite.Interpreter` but I get the same exact problem. I already searched on the Internet but nothing I tried worked...

Do you have any idea why this problem occurs ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the matching version of the TensorFlow pip, which is used for the TFLite conversion instead of the tflite_runtime library for your case.

The above tflite_runtime package is not aligned with the TensorFlow version used for the TFLite conversion.