# How to load a tflite model as a downloadable resource from an API in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

The situation is as follows:

Some time ago, we developed two applications (Android, and iOS) to connect via REST APIs, with a server dedicated to image processing. This works to this day quite well.

However, recently a new requirement has arisen to preprocess the images offline, as mobile devices have grown in computing capabilities.

Now the problem is that for business model purposes we want to be able to do the following:

1. protect the pre-trained models, so it is not desired to use them as a resource in the apk or ipa.
2. Build a REST API service to distribute the models, and the latter allows to control the version of the model, and update it over time without the need to download an update of the app from the google and apple store.
3. Protect the tflite file by encryption, so that the downloaded resource is unusable outside the authorized app.

Are there any viable strategies to achieve these objectives? The programming languages used were:

Android -> Java

iOS -> Swift

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To download it from a REST API you can see any of the official examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883156/tflite-runtime-op-builtin-code-out-of-range-131-are-you-using-old-tflite-bi eg Image classification. As per encryption check an example I have created a year ago there https://github.com/farmaker47/Speech_Commands_Kotlin (check the readme file for details). It seems that the TensorFlow team has not provided an option yet to encrypt the tflite file so you have to make it the traditional way.