# Cannot create interpreter: Op builtin_code out of range: 142. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, build.gradle, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to start an on device training sesion.

I created and converted a trasfer learning model similarly as the one shown in the example provided by tensorflow [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/model_personalization/transfer_learning/generate_training_model.py)

In the android app the model is used via a tflite Interpreter.

The problem is that if i load my model in the example app provided by tensorflow everything runs smootly but if i load it in my own app i get the following error when the interpreter is initialized

> Cannot create interpreter: Op builtin_code out of range: 142. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model?
> Registration failed.

However i simply cannot understand why this error appears giving that i use the same dependecies as the one shown in the example.

App dependency used

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
// This dependency adds the necessary TF op support.
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```

Transfer api dependency used

```
    // This dependency is compileOnly so that the user of this library can select between
// different TFLite distributions (e.g. with or without Flex).
compileOnly 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'

implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'

// This dependency adds the necessary TF op support.
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```

When i go into each Interpreter declaration from the two android applications ( the one provided in the tensorflow example and the one i created ) i can see they use different Interpreter classes.

My question is how it is possible that both projects have the same tflite versions in the gradle build but they use different versions of the package? And how could i resolve this ?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883156/tflite-runtime-op-builtin-code-out-of-range-131-are-you-using-old-tflite-bi it seems it has an answer to the point of the problem.

Comment: Thanks allot for the reply, my versions were matching but i resolved it finally by changing the version to 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+' and 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:+' insead of the nighly version.